# How to get full word from array instead of first letter in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

So I have this code:

```
search_init = 'the string'
search = search_init.replace(' ', '+')
search_array = search.strip("+")
print search_array[1]
```

I expect to get "string" in the console's print. But instead I get "h". How can I solve this? I am trying to split "the string" into an array and then pull individual words from the array. (sorry for the newbie question lol)

Comment: Maybe you are just using  `.strip('+')` when you really want to use `.split('+')`?

Comment: I think you are confusing between `strip()` and `split()`. There's no need of `replace`>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a `split` based on space and then extract from index 1.

```
search_init = 'the string'
search = search_init.split(" ")
print search[1]
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I feel dumb for that one. Will mark this as solution in 5 minutes when stackoverflow allows me. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it helped!